# Localstack 2.0 Cloud Pods Loads 2 Lambda Pods Fails

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, localstack

I'm trying to load 2 cloud pods with 2 lambda function into my environment. If I load each, they work fine. However, if I try to load them one after the other, only the last exists in the env.(it seems second cloud pod overrides by the first one). How can i load two cloud pods with lamabdas such that I'll end up with 2 working functions(and not just the last one).
It's worth mentioning that in documentation it says you can run git pod with -s hint and determine merging strategy(https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/tools/cloud-pods/pods-cli/#load). This indeed sounds really promising, however when i tried it in cli, it won't receive this hint and it says it does not exists. would appreciate your help.

Comment: Currently, we are in the process of reworking the Cloud pods, which means that the merge strategies are not available in the new pods implementation. We will update the documentation to reflect this change.
Although we do plan to reintroduce the pod merge strategies in the future, we are unable to provide a specific timeline at this moment. However, it would be immensely helpful if you could inform us about the services you primarily use with pods and provide insights on what the merge scenarios should look like.